# Cannot connect Node.js to MongoDB connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create an API where when called 5 nearest locations from the lat and long of the user is displayed.

API
`<API URL>?latitude=48.858093&longitude=2.294694`

MongoDB URL
`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.<something>.mongodb.net/`

When I test the API in Postman, I get `Cannot POST /`

When I test locally, the code cannot connect to MongoDB.

I am not sure what is wrong with the logic. And the MongoDB connection string I am using works. I can use it to log in with Compass.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const axios = require('axios');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const config = {
  mongodbUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
  foursquareClientId: process.env.FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID,
  foursquareClientSecret: process.env.FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  foursquareApiKey: process.env.FOURSQUARE_API_KEY,
  jwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
};

if (!config.mongodbUrl) {
  console.error('MONGODB_URL is not defined. Make sure to set the environment variable.');
  process.exit(1);
}

mongoose
  .connect(config.mongodbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', err));

const venueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  location: {
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number,
  },
});
const Venue = mongoose.model('Venue', venueSchema);

const authorizedUser = {
  id: 1,
  username: config.adminUser,
  password: config.adminPassword,
};

const login = (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (username === authorizedUser.username && password === authorizedUser.password) {
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: authorizedUser.id }, config.jwtSecret, { expiresIn: '1h' });
    res.json({ token });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid credentials' });
  }
};

const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Missing authentication token' });
  }

  try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, config.jwtSecret);
    req.user = decodedToken;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' });
  }
};

const getVenuesNearby = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { latitude, longitude } = req.query;

    const response = await axios.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/search', {
      params: {
        ll: `${latitude},${longitude}`,
        radius: 5000, // 5 miles in meters
        client_id: config.foursquareClientId,
        client_secret: config.foursquareClientSecret,
        client_api_key: config.foursquareApiKey,
        v: '20230725',
      },
    });

    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.error('Error fetching venues from Foursquare API:', response.statusText);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error fetching venues' });
    }
    console.log('Response data:', response.data);

    const venues = response.data.response.venues.map((venue) => ({
      name: venue.name,
      location: {
        lat: venue.location.lat,
        lng: venue.location.lng,
      },
    }));

    const savedVenues = await Venue.insertMany(venues);

    res.json({ venues: savedVenues });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching venues from Foursquare API:', err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error fetching venues' });
  }
};

app.post('/api/v1/auth/login', login);
app.get('/api/v1/venues/nearby', authenticate, getVenuesNearby);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
    mongodbURL: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
    foursquareClientId: process.env.FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID,
    foursquareClientSecret: process.env.FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    jwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
    adminUser: process.env.ADMIN_USER_NAME,
    adminPassword: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD,
  };
```

.env

```
MONGODB_URL=
FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_ID=
FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET=
FOURSQUARE_API_KEY=
JWT_SECRET_KEY=
```

Comment: What is the error message? What is the connection string?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.<something>.mongodb.net/

Comment: Did you white-list your IP in MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: I have. And I can access the DB in the MongoDB Compass app with the same exact connection string.

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable TLS/SSL, see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/ssl.html It is a bit difficult to give an answer without any error message.

Comment: I hardcoded it and now it works. There might be an issue with how I am using environment variables.